# background bluetooth notification - higher energy impact than foreground

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an application which notify on BLE device characteristic (gyroscope data).

**setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)**

When checking energy impact in Xcode I can see that application being in foreground state has less energy impact that the same application beeing in background (see attached image)
[image: Foreground and background energy impact]
Is it some Xcode bug or it really takes more power being in background, and why?

Thanks, MuniekMg

Comment: I would guess because your suspended process need to be moved into the background and then suspended again.  This has a higher impact than simply delivering a notification to code that is already executing.

Comment: Paul, do you know any way to reduce energy impact when getting bluetooth notifications in background?

Comment: get less frequent updates?  You probably shouldn't worry, the battery impact is unlikely to be that big a deal, but running a task in the background will always use more battery than not running anything in the background.  If the user wants to collect data continuously they have to expect impact on battery life

Comment: Yes, but updates frequency depends on BLE device not iOS application

Comment: Yes.  That is why I added my second statement.  Basically, it is what it is.  The energy used is the energy used.  You should use real-world testing to see if it is a problem, don't rely on Xcode

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll do it